# Runtime Error 1004 / Error 438 when getting the Text property of a copied button, setting the property works though

Tags: excel, vba, button, runtime-error

I've inserted a large number of form controll buttons (with the text "") into an excel worksheet by copy'n'pasting (from another workbook).

[image: example]

These buttons are connected to this macro (which is located in PERSONAL.XLSB):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeSomething()
    ' The button which called the macro.
    Dim b As Button
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)

    ' Do run the code if the button was not already active.
    If b.Text <> "x" Then        ' SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM
        ' Do something

        ' Mark the button as activated.
        b.Text = "x"
        b.Font.Bold = True

    ' If the button was already activated, deactivate it.
    Else
        'Mark the button as deactivated.
        b.Text = " "
    End If
End Sub
```

This set up worked properly before. But since copying, I get `Runtime Error 1004` *"Unable to set the Text property of the Button class"*.

When handled, the exception seems to be `Error 438` *"Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method"*.

The Debugging marks the line:

```
If b.Text <> "x" Then
```

---

**What puzzles me is that getting the text property seems to throw the runtime error, but setting the value runs just fine**:

```
b.Text = "x"
```

The correct Button in the correct Worksheet of the correct Workbook is changed.

---

As soon as I change the text of the button manually to something other than "", the macro also seems to work.

Unfortunately, the inserted buttons do not appear to be included in the list returned by `ActiveSheet.Buttons`, so I can not loop over them to change their values.

---

I'm not sure if that's appropriate, but I've uploaded [here](https://uploadfiles.io/qnla4yc6) a sample file.

Comment: If these are ActiveX, try `b.Caption`.

Comment: If they are ActiveX change them to a FormControl. I would stay away from ActiveX where ever possible. ActiveX is full of bugs. If you can use a FormControl instead prefer the FormControl.

Comment: Those buttons are Form Controlls. Sorry for the vagueness of my statement.

I had difficulties with ActiveX from the beginning.

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce the issue. It works for me. Does `Set b = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)` fix it? If not can you providec a [mcve]?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Unfortunately, the same error still occurs. 
It's almost as if the worksheet is not aware of the buttons, until their values change.

Comment: I guess it has either something to do with that `ActiveSheet` is not the sheet you expect it to be, or you maybe have multiple buttons with the same name. Put a `Debug.Print Application.Caller, b.Parent.Name, b.Parent.Parent.Name` behind the `Set b = …` line and see what the output in the immediate window is after you clicked a button.

Comment: Try a different property like `Caption`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I'm not sure if that's appropriate, but I've uploaded a sample file [here](https://ufile.io/qnla4yc6).

Comment: As you **copy'n'pasted** the buttons, can you check there names? Also, after you set `b`, can you look at the properties of `b` to identify what it is?

Comment: I have no idea what you did to that button. But if I right click on it and select "Edit Text" from the context menu. Then just click into any cell and it works. If I add a new button myself it works too. So you must have inserted a strange broken button, no idea how but I suggest to delete them and insert new ones.

Comment: @TimWilliams Unfortunately, `Caption` throws the same Runtime Error.

Comment: @Zac The Names are e.g. "button 1762", "button 1767", and so on. `TypeName(ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller))` returns `Button` (I don't know how to verify that further).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Lucky me. At least I'm not the only one who's confused by that behaviour. Thanks for the effort to all concerned.

Comment: @AFoeee is it solved now?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Since newly added buttons do not show the behavior, I will probably delete all existing buttons. This workaround currently seems to be the only solution.

Comment: You reference "ActiveWorkbook. If the active workbook is not the one you are expecting and it doesn't have the form controls you will get the error.

Comment: @SmileyFtW I would expect the ActiveWorkbook to be the one I "just" pushed the button in. What confuses me is that `b.Text = "asdf "` executes and changes the right button in the right workbook. Only the evaluation of the content (before any changes) seems to cause the error

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at "If b.text = ..." line and then inspect b in the locals window what do you see?

Comment: Also, what reference do you have set in your Personal.xls to get the Button type? The buttons are actually shapes.

Comment: @SmileyFtW [Name: `b`, Typ: `Button/Button`] ...
[Name: `b.Text`, Wert: `<Unable to set the Text property of Button class>`, Typ: `String`]. Same Error goes for "AddIndent" and "Caption", besides that the other values look good.

Comment: @SmileyFtW As far as I know, I have no references set in my PERSONAL.XLSB (although I do not quite understand the question). There should be just the macro in it.

Comment: There is no "Button" type that I am aware of. When I tried to duplicate your issue to investigate I did "Dim b As " and intellisense does not have a "Buttom" type (class). It has a Shape class that contains things like your form control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your question has the right details. If these buttons are indeed Form Controls - and I think they must be because I believe ActiveX controls don't return a `Caller` - then their parent object is `Shapes`, and you would call the `Text` property from the `Shape.TextFrame.Characters` object.

I wonder if your original worksheet had a`Collection` object called *Buttons*
which contained, perhaps, a list of the buttons in the form of a class object, called *Button* (hence your error message) and which exposes the properties that are called in your code.

Without that collection and class, the code would be more like this:

```
Public Sub ChangeSomething()
    Dim btn As Shape

    With Application
        'Check for correct data types.
        If Not TypeOf .ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub
        If IsObject(.Caller) Then Exit Sub

        'Acquire button
        On Error Resume Next
        Set btn = .ActiveSheet.Shapes(.Caller)
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Check for a found button
        If btn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End With

    'Check for non-actionable button.
    With btn.TextFrame.Characters
        If .Count = 0 Then
            .Text = "x"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    'If we've reached here, it's an actionable button.
    Debug.Print "Do something."

    'Clear the button text.
    btn.TextFrame.Characters.Text = ""

End Sub
```

I rather suspect some half-copied code here, and the rest of the project remains elsewhere.

Comment: I agree that there is likely a Button class that has not been included and the code to collect them is also missing.

Comment: If I replace my code with the code above, the error no longer occurs. Thank you!